Dynamic assignment of joints to ros2_controllers
Is it possible to assign all joints of a robot (or a series of specific joints according to a pattern, e.g. left_joint_*) to a controller in the controller configuration YAML or does each joint currently have to be named explicitly?
So is there something possible like:
position_controller:
type: velocity_controllers/JointGroupVelocityController

position_controller:
  ros__parameters:
    joints:
      - left_joint_*

For a robot consisting of a dynamic number of joints (Xacro and python launch files do the magic here and there are said to be robots that consist of a large number of identical joints), it would make sense to assign the controllers according to the joints that actually occur.
Of course you could have the yaml file generated dynamically, but with the JointStateBroadcaster, for example, you can specify that all joints should be assigned by omitting the joint parameter.
What would be the current best practice for this? Is such functionality planned or deliberately not planned for ros2_control? Was there such a thing in ROS (1)?

Currently, this is not possible.
You could implement the wildcards in your controller while parsing the parameters.
But: Controller manager does not support the change of DOF while a controller is active (we also discouraged this in all released ros2_controllers by setting the parameters read-only), which means that you will have to go through the lifecycle and reconfigure your controller.
I'm not saying that this would be impossible, but you'll have to convince the maintainers with a valid usecase and provide a PR implementing this feature.
